# Using VBA to Open Another Excel File with Personal Workbook Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that formats a report. I would like to include this macro in my personal workbook, however a part of the code references a second workbook and copies the format from that workbook over. The macro is only partially working (some worksheets are not formatted the way I want) using the personal workbook, and I think it's not working entirely because I'm referencing another workbook. When I run the macro on its own, everything works fine. Is there something that I am missing in my code?

```
Sub Format()
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        Rows("1:11").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Rows("12:12").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        ws.Range("A4") = ws.Name
        Range("A4").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
    Next ws


    Range("D13:E222").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    xlApp.Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Automation\Format.xlsm"
    Sheets("All_Leadsheet").Select

    Range("A1:O233").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Activate
    Range("A1:N471").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select


    Columns("A:F").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 40
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        .Orientation = 0
    End With

    Windows("Format.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete (there is a missing `end sub`)

Comment: I've only included a portion of the code. Do you need the code in its entirety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the main problem you were having is that you were referencing sheets() and range() without specifying where they were located so VBA was guessing. And I'm guessing that VBA was guessing the personal workbook and it's sheets instead of the workbook you were wanting to perform your actions on.

I had to guess at a little bit of what you were doing here but the main thing you should take away from my changes is that you don't need to necessarily select a cell before making changes to it. I'm guessing this came from you recording the macro (great way of learning by the way). But this will slow down your macro, only select when you actually need it selected. This actually goes for sheets too, you don't have to have a sheet active to make changes in it. Hope this helps.

```
Sub Format()

Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Move Before:=Sheets(1)
wb.Sheets("not sure which sheet you want").Rows("1:1").Delete 'Shift:=xlUp

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Rows("1:11").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    With ws.Rows("12:12")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ws.Range("A4") = ws.Name
    Range("A4").Font.Bold = True
    'On Error Resume Next 'Careful with these, all your errors will now just resume next
    'Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate 'Next ws takes care of this, unless you are wanting to skip two worksheets
    'If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
Next ws

Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
ws.Activate

ws.Range("D13:E222").ClearContents

xlApp.Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Automation\Format.xlsm" 'Where is xlApp set at?


Set ws = Sheets("All_Leadsheet")

ws.Range("A1:O233").Copy
'ActiveWorkbook.Activate 'active workbook should already be active
ws.Range("A1:N471").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'ws.Range("A1").Select


With ws.Columns("A:F")
    .ColumnWidth = 40
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = True '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    .Orientation = 0
End With

Windows("Format.xlsm").Close savechanges:=False 'Not sure what this file is? Perhaps the individual file before
                                                'moving it to personal workbook? If so delete this.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Jason. That helped out a lot and the code is working the way it should now. A colleague of mine initially wrote this so I was struggling with understanding the code and how to make it work in a personal workbook. Thanks again for your help.